# Explain me ways to understand this complex query

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone help me to understand this big sql query. How do I break it down in small chunks to understand it ?

```
select t.Instrument as Instrument ,ClearingId as ClearingId,
        ISNULL( PrevQty ,0) AS PrevQty,SettlePrice,
        ISNULL(TodayBuyQty,0) as TodayBuyQty,
        ISNULL( TodaySellQty ,0) AS TodaySellQty, 
        ISNULL(PrevQty +TodayBuyQty-TodaySellQty,0) as NetQty, 
        TodayBuyPrice, TodaySellPrice,LTP,PnL,Token 
from
(
    select Instrument,w.ClearingId as ClearingId,
            ISNULL( PrevQty ,0) AS PrevQty,ISNULL(TodayBuyQty,0) as TodayBuyQty,
            ISNULL( TodaySellQty ,0) AS TodaySellQty, 
            TodayAvgBuyPrice as TodayBuyPrice,TodayAvgSellPrice as TodaySellPrice,
            LTP,PnL,w.Token 
    from
    (
        select Symbol as Instrument, ClearingId,  
                ISNULL(TodayBuyQty,0) as TodayBuyQty, 
                TodayAvgBuyPrice, 
                ISNULL( -TodaySellQty ,0) AS TodaySellQty, 
                TodayAvgSellPrice, NULL as  LTP ,NULL as  PnL , 
                w.Token as Token 
        from
        (
            select Token, sum(Qty) as NetPositionQty, ClearingId,
                    sum(CASE WHEN Qty < 0 THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) as TodaySellQty, 
                    sum(CASE WHEN Qty > 0 THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) as TodayBuyQty,
                    sum(CASE WHEN Qty < 0 THEN Qty * Price ELSE 0 END) 
                    / 
                    NULLIF(sum(CASE WHEN Qty < 0 THEN Qty ELSE 0 END), 0) as TodayAvgSellPrice,
                    sum(CASE WHEN Qty > 0 THEN Qty * Price ELSE 0 END) 
                    / 
                    NULLIF(sum(CASE WHEN Qty > 0 THEN Qty ELSE 0 END), 0) as TodayAvgBuyPrice 
            from
            (
                select m.Token, 
                    (CASE WHEN ClearingId = 'SATP' THEN 'STRAITS' ELSE CASE WHEN ClearingId = 'BATP' THEN 'BPI' ELSE 'UOB' END END ) as ClearingId , 
                    Price/CAST(Multiplier AS float ) as Price,Qty 
                from 
                (
                    select Token , Exchange as ClearingId , 
                            LastTradePrice as Price ,
                            CASE WHEN  Side = 'S' THEN -LastTradeQuantity  ELSE LastTradeQuantity  END as Qty   
                    from Strategy_Orders 
                    where ExchangeStatus in (9,10) )m 
                        JOIN TokenMap t ON ( m.Token = t.Token) 
                    UNION ALL
                    select m.Token, (CASE WHEN ClearingId = 'SATP' THEN 'STRAITS' ELSE CASE WHEN ClearingId = 'BATP' THEN 'BPI' ELSE 'UOB' END END ) as ClearingId , 
                            Price/CAST(Multiplier AS float ) as Price,
                            Qty 
                    from 
                    (
                        select Token , Exchange as ClearingId ,
                                LastTradePrice as Price ,
                                CASE WHEN  Side = 'S' THEN -LastTradeQuantity  ELSE LastTradeQuantity  END as Qty   
                        from Manual_Orders 
                        where ExchangeStatus in (9,10) )m 
                            JOIN TokenMap t ON ( m.Token = t.Token) 
                        UNION ALL
                        select  Token , ClearingId , TodayBuyPrice  , 
                                TodayBuyQty as Qty  
                        from EOD_Holdings 
                        where CurrentDate = 
                            ( select top 1 CurrentDAte from EOD_Holdings 
                              order by CurrentDAte desc 
                    ) 
                    UNION ALL
                    select Token , ClearingId , TodaySellPrice ,
                            TodaySellQty as Qty  
                    from EOD_Holdings 
                    where CurrentDate = ( 
                        select top 1 CurrentDAte from EOD_Holdings 
                        order by CurrentDAte desc 
                        )
                ) x 
            group by Token,ClearingId) w 
                JOIN(select Token, Symbol from TokenMAp ) h on w.Token = h.Token
            ) w  
            FULL OUTER JOIN(
                select Token, PrevQty , ClearingId 
                from EOD_Holdings 
                where CurrentDate = ( select top 1 CurrentDAte from EOD_Holdings order by CurrentDAte desc 
                                    ) 
        ) h 
            on w.Token = h.Token and w.ClearingId = h.ClearingId 
    )t 
    JOIN (
            select * from LatestSettlePrices 
        ) sp 
        on t.Instrument = sp.Instrument
```

Comment: First you [hit the SQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/)

Comment: Then, copy out each 'Select' statement individually, and understand what each one does,  then understand how they all relate to each other in the main query.

Comment: This is not a tutorial site. Find a good SQL tutorial online and follow it, and learn how individual portions of this SQL work, and you'll be able to put them together.

Answer (score 0):

You can break the query into chunks by looking at each subquery ("select ..." ) separately and running them to see the results. You need to start with the innermost queries that do not have other select statements in the "from" or "where" clause.

Also note that this query does not seem to be a clear, neither an optimal solution.
You would want to avoid using full outer joins and union all statements for the best performance.